# Postgres Case update syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I've done this update script:

```
    UPDATE etude
SET id_enseigne
(CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 1 THEN 6
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 1 THEN 6
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 2 THEN 26
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 3 THEN 2122
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 4 THEN 1960
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 5 THEN 84
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 6 THEN 103
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 7 THEN 56
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 8 THEN 108
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 9 THEN 68
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 10 THEN 489
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 11 THEN 1124
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 13 THEN 502
ELSE CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 14 THEN 1298


ELSE 0 END)
```

But I get this error, I don't understand why, because it is supposed to be simple:

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3: (CASE WHEN id_enseigne= 1 THEN 6
        ^
********** Erreur **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
État SQL :42601
Caractère : 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This other [`case` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) is more convenient:

```
update etude
set id_enseigne = case id_enseigne
    when 1 then 6
    when 2 then 26
    when 3 then 2122
    when 4 then 1960
    when 5 then 84
    when 6 then 103
    when 7 then 56
    when 8 then 108
    when 9 then 68
    when 10 then 489
    when 11 then 1124
    when 13 then 502
    when 14 then 1298
    else 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the assignment operator. You could keep or lose the parenthesis though.

```
UPDATE etude
SET    id_enseigne = CASE ...
-- Here -----------^
```